# Django multilanguage text and saving it on mysql

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with multilanguage and multi character encoded text. 
Project use OpenGraph and it will save in mysql database some information from websites. But database have problem with character encoding. I tryed encoding them  to byte. That is problem, becouse in admin panel text show us bute and it is not readable. 
Please help me. How can i save multilanguage text in database and if i need encode to byte them how can i correctly decode them in admin panel and in views

Answer (score 0):

You should encode all data as UTF-8 which is unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solve not so right but I want share it. 
I replacid my multilanguage fields in BinaryField and before saving  encode them.
Finded [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate](http://this) package and before encoding transliterate them. 
Created new table OneToOne (or new column) and save translitarated there.